# I tried to connect to my web service using JSON in my android app, but I got this error:

Tags: android, json, web-services

> E/test(20965): Exception  E/AndroidRuntime(20965): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main  E/AndroidRuntime(20965): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{sliit.mad.contact_list/sliit.mad.contact_list.TEST}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException  E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) E/AndroidRuntime(20965): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException  E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   sliit.mad.contact_list.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:65) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   sliit.mad.contact_list.TEST.onCreate(TEST.java:38) 
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20965):... 11 more

Comment: can you post some code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you already had fixed this issue. but this issue was caused by that you tried to do network operation in the main UI thread and that is not allowed.

The exception log can explain itself.

> E/AndroidRuntime(20965): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException E/AndroidRuntime(20965):at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)